# ruby: when copying streams, how to make it pass input characters?

Tags: ruby, unix, command-line-interface, expect

To better describe my problem, I have a ruby script which builds an expect script, writes it to a file and calls #exec with the file path:

```
expect /tmp/expectscript
```

Problem is, I lose control after I call exec, and can't clean that file. I also have credentials, so it's a no go.

I'm now trying to pass the script as a string to stdin, but that's impossible using ruby + exec, so I rewrote it to open3. All went well, until I saw that stuff like tabs and backspace is not properly handled by the streams. Here's a reproduction:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
require 'open3'                              
Open3.popen3("expect -") do |i, o, e, t|     
  Thread.start { IO.copy_stream(o, $stdout) }
  Thread.start { IO.copy_stream(e, $stderr) }
  i << "spawn bash\ninteract\nwait\nexit\n"  
  Thread.start { IO.copy_stream($stdin, i) } 
  t.value                                    
end
```

Now try to run this, write "ls" and press "TAB". or backspace, for that matter. the shell output is not autocompleting.

This seems to be a problem with the copy_stream function, which is maybe handling certain characters before it copies them. Is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the missing piece:

```
$stdin.raw!
```

It wasn't that hard after all.

Comment: must also note, this is required for the call to work:   ```require "io/console"```